# Need Subversion pre-commit hook to block check-ins by a specific user

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server, pre-commit-hook

I have Subversion installed on Windows Server 2008.  I want to add code to the pre-commit.bat to block commits by domain user jdoe on domain foo.  What does that code look like?  I am assuming it will use C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.

Answer (score 1):

[svnlook author](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.author.html), but **do not engage in this nonsense** - re-read about path-based authorization and revoke write access for needed user in needed area. Period.

Comment: I tried adding an entry to the authz file in the root repository's conf folder, but could not get this to work.  I thought a pre-commit hook might be easier because I am currently using one to block commits that are missing a check -in comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is my pre-commit.bat.  It is ugly, but it works.  The first check blocks commits that are missing a comment.  The second check blocks commits by user jdoe.

```
@echo off
::    
:: Stops commits that have empty log messages.
::

@echo off

setlocal

rem Subversion sends through the path to the repository and transaction id
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

rem check for an empty log message
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook" log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > nul
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else (goto nextcheck)

rem block commits by user jdoe
:nextcheck
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook" author %REPOS% -t %TXN% > c:\windows\temp\author.txt
set /p authorcommitting=<c:\windows\temp\author.txt
if %authorcommitting%==jdoe (goto err1) else exit 0

:err
echo. 1>&2
echo Your commit has been blocked because you didn't supply a log message  1>&2
echo. 1>&2
echo Please add a log message describing the reason for your changes and 1>&2
echo then commit. 1>&2
echo. 1>&2
exit 1

:err1
echo. 1>&2
echo Commits are blocked for this user 1>&2
echo. 1>&2
exit 1
```

Comment: You should not be using the hooks as authorization mechanism. You should use path-based authorization for that https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the [VisualSVN Server Getting Started](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) guide and the section [Configuring User Permissions](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions) in particular.

VisualSVN Server offers a UI to manage the user permissions. You can use the [VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions), [PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) or [RepoCfg](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/delegation/) to manage the permissions.

Don't forget that SVN server administrators and repository supervisors must understand the access control principles in Subversion. Read the article [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) for more information.